# EJB3 - JSF cannot update entity it excute insert statement why?

Tags: jsf, ejb

hello all new problem i cant solved 
i have 1 entity below

```
package com.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author Kency
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "about")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "About.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM About a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "About.findByAboutTitle", query = "SELECT a FROM About a WHERE a.aboutTitle = :aboutTitle")})
public class About implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "about_title")
    private String aboutTitle;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    public About() {
    }

   /* public About(String aboutTitle) {
        this.aboutTitle = aboutTitle;
    }*/

    public About(String aboutTitle, String content) {
        this.aboutTitle = aboutTitle;
        this.content = content;
    }
    public About(String aboutTitle) {
        this.aboutTitle = aboutTitle;
    }

    public String getAboutTitle() {
        return aboutTitle;
    }

    public void setAboutTitle(String aboutTitle) {
        this.aboutTitle = aboutTitle;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (aboutTitle != null ? aboutTitle.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof About)) {
            return false;
        }
        About other = (About) object;
        if ((this.aboutTitle == null && other.aboutTitle != null) || (this.aboutTitle != null && !this.aboutTitle.equals(other.aboutTitle))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.entity.About[aboutTitle=" + aboutTitle + "]";
    }

}
```

my stateless bean

```
package com.DAO;

import com.entity.About;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author Kency
 */
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AboutDAO {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mcGrawLibPro-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public About retrieveAbout(){
       Query query = em.createNamedQuery("About.findAll");
       return (About) query.getSingleResult();
    }

    public void persist(Object object) {
        em.persist(object);
    }

    public About updateAbout(About abouts){
       return em.merge(abouts);

    }

    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")

}
```

my JSF managed bean controller

```
package com.mcgraw.controller;

import com.DAO.AboutDAO;
import com.entity.About;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

/**
 *
 * @author Kency
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AboutController implements Serializable{
    @EJB
    private AboutDAO aboutDAO;
    private About about ;
    private String toolbar = "maxi";




    public String getToolbar() {
        return toolbar;
    }

    public void setToolbar(String toolbar) {
        this.toolbar = toolbar;
    }

    public About getAbout() {
        return aboutDAO.retrieveAbout();
    }


    public void setAbout(About about) {
        this.about = about;
    }


    /** Creates a new instance of AboutController */
    public AboutController() {
       about = new About();
    }

    public void updateAbout(){
        about = aboutDAO.updateAbout(about);
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
            "", "Update ok"));

    }

}
```

my JSF page code

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="about" header="About">
    <f:view>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{aboutController.about.aboutTitle}"/>
            <p:editor value="#{aboutController.about.content}" widgetVar="editor"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="editor.saveHTML()" action="#{aboutController.updateAbout}"/>
            <p:messages/>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>

</p:dialog>
```

my problem is when i click submit button it not update it throw exception null in insert statement 
i want update but why it insert to database??
everybody have idea for solve it ? thank you

my stacktrace

```
 WARNING: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'about_title' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO about (about_title, content) VALUES (?, ?)
        bind => [null, null]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.entity.About[aboutTitle=null])
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:801)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:867)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:530)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeCall(AbstractSession.java:914)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:334)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:177)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:461)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:286)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:675)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:589)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2857)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1225)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1207)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1167)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:3260)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1403)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:547)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1508)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3128)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:268)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:412)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:837)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5040)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4805)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2004)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1955)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:198)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
        at $Proxy114.updateAbout(Unknown Source)
        at com.DAO.__EJB31_Generated__AboutDAO__Intf____Bean__.updateAbout(Unknown Source)
        at com.mcgraw.controller.AboutController.updateAbout(AboutController.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:98)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.mcgraw.controller.UserLoginFilter.doFilter(UserLoginFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.mcgraw.controller.UserLoginFilter.doFilter(UserLoginFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'about_title' cannot be null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2327)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2312)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:792)
        ... 91 more
```

column **content** in database type is TEXT

Comment: Can you update your question to include the exception stack trace?

Comment: everybody have any ideas? please help me

Answer (score 1):

You've bound your JSF input element to `#{aboutController.about}`.  This invokes the getter:

```
public About getAbout() {
    return aboutDAO.retrieveAbout();
}
```

Which in turn invokes the DB query:

```
public About retrieveAbout(){
   Query query = em.createNamedQuery("About.findAll");
   return (About) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

So you are getting a new About object every time the getter is invoked.  What you should be doing is binding to a specific "about" instance, then sending that instance back to your Stateless Session Bean to be updated.  You store this "about" instance as the property of your Managed Bean, and return that with the Managed Bean's getter.

Comment: Hi Brian i want to update not insert about object, i was solved my problem in getter method `public About getAbout() {
        //return aboutDAO.retrieveAbout("About");
        this.about = aboutDAO.retrieveAbout("About");
        return about;
    }` it work well !! thank you for support me